# Expected value of drawing bills

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

There are 2 $\$10$ bills, 2 $\$20$ bills, and 1 $\$50$ bill inside a box. You draw four bills at random. What is the expected value of amount that you have (assuming draws are without replacement)?

My approach: Expected value of bills from the box is $2/5*10 + 2/5*20 + 1/5*50 = 22$
I have a couple of questions at this point-

1. If draws are with replacement, then the expected value is simply 22*4 by linearity of expectations, am I correct?
2. How to approach this when the draws are without replacement?

Edit: I have corrected the arithmetic error as pointed out in the comments and the answer.

Comment: What you have is for $1$ bill. You are drawing $4$ bills.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, I multiply by 4 in point 1.

Comment: Yes then it is correct and it should not matter whether it is with replacement or without.

Comment: @MathLover I find it surprising that with and without replacement doesn't matter here. Is it that obvious? What is the intuition? Thanks.

Comment: Linearity of expectation removes the issue of dependence (and thereby removes the role of replacement).  Each bill has an equal chance of being drawn, that's all you need for the computation.

Comment: btw as the answer pointed out, the calculation should show $22$ and not $18$. I did not notice there was a calculation mistake.

Comment: To your other confusion, if you have $4$ cards, one each of $4$ different colors including red, what is the probability that the first card drawn is red? what is the probability that the last card  drawn is red? What would you answer for with replacement and without replacement? It is the same thing.

Comment: Thanks to both of the answers above. It certainly resolves my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. If draws are with replacement, then the expected value is simply 18*4 by linearity of expectations, am I correct?

The principle of multiplying the expected value for one draw by four is correct.  That's a nice observation of the independence between the draws.  However, be careful with the arithmetic.

Let $\$X$ be the value of the bill drawn.

$$\text{expected value of the bill} = \$E[X] = \$10 \cdot P(X = 10) + \$20 \cdot P(X = 20) + \$50 \cdot P(X = 50) \\
= \$\left(10 \cdot \frac25+ 20 \cdot \frac25 + 50 \cdot \frac15\right) = \$(4 + 8 + 10) = \$22$$

Hence the expected value of drawing four bills with replacement is $\$4E[X] = \$4(22) = \$88$.

> 2. How to approach this when the draws are without replacement?

You have five bills in total.  When you draw four bills from them, only one bill is left, so the answer is simple: $\$(10\cdot2+20\cdot2+50\cdot1-E[X]) = \$(110 - 22) = \$88$.